# Control over proportions using randi (or something else )

Tags: matlab

I have this line in code that defines a certain number of agents within the selected area

```
  obj.agents = randi([0 1],obj.width, obj.height);
```

I want to control this parameter so I have a certain proportion of 0 and 1 randomly distributed within the area, like 30% of 0 and 70% of 1, and vice versa (so they still randomly distributed, but one is bigger than the other ).

Are there any relatively easy ways of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize it as a matrix of [ones](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ones.html) and then replace random 30% indices with zeros.

```
obj.agents = ones(obj.width, obj.height);
inds = randperm(obj.width*obj.height, 0.3*obj.width*obj.height);
obj.agents(inds) = 0;
```

<sub>Caveat: If 30% is not an integer then you'd have to use one of these: [`ceil`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html), [`floor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html), [`round`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) or [`fix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fix.html); whichever suits your needs.</sub>